# using file directories with double backslashes in cmd using python

Tags: python, cmd

let's assume that this is a file path which is obtained using a python script:

```
f_path = os.getcwd() + "\\" +'out.dat'
```

the value of this variable is, for example:

```
'C:\\My Python\\output\\out.dat'
```

Now I want to open this file using an external program (extProg) via cmd. something like this:

```
cmd_to_parse = 'extProg ' + f_path
os.system(cmd_to_parse)
```

I got the following error though:

```
couldn't read file "E:\My": no such file or directory
```

which is probably due to double backslashes in the file path. how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Combine path parts with `os.path.join` instead.

Comment: The problem is the the space in the file name, ie "My Python".

Comment: Notice how the path is spit up at the *space*, not the backslash. That is likely your problem. Try using `subprocess` instead of `os.system`.

Comment: escape the space with a back slash

Comment: @Evert I've tried `subprocess.call(['extProg',f_path])`. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use quotation marks around paths with spaces `'"C:\\My Python\\output\\out.dat"'`, for example:

```
cmd_to_parse = 'extProg ' + '"' + f_path + '"'
```

Comment: Note that CMD will strip the first and last quote if the executable is a quoted path, which will ruin the quoting of `f_path`. In this case, wrap the entire command in double quotes. For example, `'"' + '"' + r'C:\Program Files\app\app.exe' + '"' + ' ' + '"' + f_path + '"' + '"'`. subprocess with `shell=True` does this for you.